# What permissions does the facebook app need in order to post on the timeline of the user who logged in using Facebook Login?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am building an iOS app where user takes a photo, writes title, description and then posts it on his/her timeline. Before an actual posting takes place user has to login using Facebook and authorize himself/herself.

Our backend is on Ruby on Rails and I am using koala GEM.

So, when user logs in using facebook and reaches an authentication screen it says "This app doesn't post on facebook" however, that is exactly what I want it to do. So, I am confused as to what permissions do I need from facebook so users can post on their own timelines using my app.

It is certainly not user_posts. What permissions do I need?

Comment: user_posts is for reading the users posts. publish_actions is for posting

Comment: Wow. Thanks WizKid. I do have this permission which is good but now when I generate An access token by selecting 'publis_actions' using Graph API Explorer is different from the one that is returned by following method in my code

Comment: if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
  let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

print(accessToken)
}

Comment: Access tokens may of course differ. What’s the problem with that?

Comment: I want an AccessToken with publish_actions permission but the one I am getting it with FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString is not the one I need

Comment: I figured it out.

let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
loginButton.publishPermissions = ["publish_actions"]